# How to convert columns in a dataframe into time series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

So I selected 3 columns from my dataframe in order to create a time series that I could then plot:

```
booking_date = pd.DataFrame({'day': hotel_bookings_cleaned["arrival_date_day_of_month"],
                             'month': hotel_bookings_cleaned["arrival_date_month"],
                             'year': hotel_bookings_cleaned["arrival_date_year"]})
```

and the output looks like:

```
day month   year
0   1   July    2015
1   1   July    2015
2   1   July    2015
3   1   July    2015
4   1   July    2015
```

I tried using

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(booking_date)
```

but got the error message

```
ValueError: Unable to parse string "July" at position 0
```

I'm assuming I need to convert the Month column to a numeric value before I can convert it to a datetime, but I haven't been able to make any parsers work.

Comment: _but I haven't been able to make any parsers work._ Can you share the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(booking_date.astype(str).agg('-'.join, axis=1), format='%d-%B-%Y')

Out[13]:
0   2015-07-01
1   2015-07-01
2   2015-07-01
3   2015-07-01
4   2015-07-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is more performant than the previous answer, but you can convert your string column to integers with a dictionary mapping to fit the format that pandas expects in to_datetime()

```
month_map = {
'January':1,
'February':2,
'March':3,
'April':4,
'May':5,
'June':6,
'July':7,
'August':8,
'September':9,
'October':10,
'November':11,
'December':12
}

dates = pd.DataFrame({
    'day':booking_date.day,
    'month':booking_date.month.apply(lambda x: month_map[x]),
    'year':booking_date.year
})
ts = pd.to_datetime(dates)
```